# Install angular2-markdown in angular2 project

Tags: angular, npm, markdown

I am working on a angular2 project and I want to create a markdown editor. In order to achieve succh a task, I installed the [Markdown module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-markdown) by doing 
" npm install angular2-markdown --save " and then I added it  in my imports.

The problem is, when I launch my project, I have this error :

> file:///C:/Users/******/workspace/******/app/angular2-markdown.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
>   index.html:1
>
> Uncaught (in promise) Error: (SystemJS) XHR error loading file:///C:/Users/******/workspace/******/app/angular2-markdown.js
>
> Error: XHR error loading file:///C:/Users/******/workspace/******/app/angular2-markdown.js
>
> Error loading file:///C:/Users/******/workspace/******/app/angular2-markdown.js as "angular2-markdown" from file:///C:/Users/******/workspace/******/app/client/device-configurator/device-configurator.module.js

I don't understand why, can anyone help me to figure out what's going on ?

EDIT : 
My import statement is just :

> import { MarkdownModule } from 'angular2-markdown';
>
> @NgModule({
>
> > imports: [
> >     ...
> >        MarkdownModule.forRoot()
> >     ...
> >       ],
> >     ...
> >      })

My moduleResolution is node.

Comment: Can you add your `import` statement and also add the `moduleResolution` value currently in your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I've just edited  my post.